# I am trying to test login scenario of android application and verify toast messages

Tags: appium, android-toast

[Application Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxxuG.png)I am testing login scenario of an android app.
I have 7 different  Test cases
I have written code for that but it is giving error
Please check my code and error and let me know, where i am going wrong.

I have tried this code only

```
    package TestCases.Project_Entry;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;

    import PageObject.loginObjects;
    import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

    public class loginTestCases extends launch {

         @BeforeTest
    public void openapp() throws MalformedURLException {
        capabilities();
    }

    @Test
    public void CodeAndPasswordBlank() {

        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Login.click();
        String ToastMessage1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast")).getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(ToastMessage1);
        Assert.assertEquals(ToastMessage1, "can't be blank!");
    }

    @Test
    public void CodeBlankPasswordCorrect() {
        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Password.sendKeys("111111");
        log.Login.click();
        String ToastMessage2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast")).getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(ToastMessage2);
        Assert.assertEquals(ToastMessage2, "can't be blank!");

    }

    @Test
    public void CodeCorrectPasswordBlank() {
        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Code.sendKeys("111111");
        log.Login.click();
        String ToastMessage3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast")).getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(ToastMessage3);
        Assert.assertEquals(ToastMessage3, "can't be blank!");
    }

    @Test
    public void CodeIncorrectPasswordCorrect() {
        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Code.sendKeys("111112");
        log.Password.sendKeys("111111");
        log.Login.click();
        String ToastMessage4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast")).getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(ToastMessage4);
        Assert.assertEquals(ToastMessage4, "Invalid login!");
    }

    @Test
    public void CodeCorrectPasswordInorrect() {
        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Code.sendKeys("111111");
        log.Password.sendKeys("123456");
        log.Login.click();
        String ToastMessage5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast")).getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(ToastMessage5);
        Assert.assertEquals(ToastMessage5, "Invalid login!");
    }

    @Test
    public void CodeInCorrectPasswordInorrect() {
        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Code.sendKeys("111211");
        log.Password.sendKeys("123456");
        log.Login.click();
        String ToastMessage6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Toast")).getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(ToastMessage6);
        Assert.assertEquals(ToastMessage6, "Invalid login!");
    }

    @Test
    public void CodeCorrectPasswordCorrect() {
        loginObjects log = new loginObjects(driver);
        log.Code.sendKeys("111111");
        log.Password.sendKeys("111111");
        log.Login.click();
        AndroidElement SelectGroup = driver.findElement(By.id("android:id/alertTitle"));
        SelectGroup.isDisplayed();
    }

}
```

Only these two getting passed.

PASSED: CodeAndPasswordBlank
PASSED: CodeBlankPasswordCorrect

Answer (score 0):

I think touching the Input field to pop-up the keyboard is missed here.
Before entering numbers you should call the keyboard by click() on Input field.
So please check this and upload a screenshot from there to better helping

Comment: Please check screen shot of my application , i have added above.

Comment: And let me know the sollution

Comment: It is happening because , my tests are running in wrong order.Please let me how to controll order of our test.

Comment: @PalakSingh You should tap directly on the input field. So you must find the element by ID then send input keys. here is a reference: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/send-keys/

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got the issue.
before every test i need to check if code and password field already has something, than i need to check this and clear it and then move further.
Please let me know how can we check this before every test.